# Is Microsoft dropping support for SDF database files in Visual Studio?

Tags: database, visual-studio, sql-server-ce

In Visual Studio 2013 there is no longer an option to create `.sdf` SQL Server Compact databases in WebPages (WebMatrix) websites. I am no longer able to view `.sdf` database files in Visual Studio either. I downloaded the latest version of WebMatrix to open my `.sdf` database but WebMatrix crashes when I open my website. When I create a new empty site and add existing files, it crashes.

I searched for days for a way to view and edit my `.sdf` database and nothing is working. I can no longer get Navicat SQL Server app to open a database. I cannot get LinqPad to open an `.sdf` database file, I cannot get Compact Viewer to open or edit `.sdf` databases. I **can** *open* `.sdf` databases with `SqlCEToolbox40.exe` but it only shows top 200 rows **and** it won't let me edit the tables.

Now I'm completely stumped. How do I view **and** edit a `.sdf` database file?

Comment: Do you have the "SQL Server Compact Design Tools" installed? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa983341.aspx

Comment: Thanks @David, I checked out that link just now and searched for it but I don't see a download link anywhere.

Comment: Here maybe http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30709

Comment: Thank you @rene, I'm downloading that now and will see how things go. But looking at the page I think I have already installed that. But we'll see..

Comment: Ah, yep. It's only giving me option to repair or remove, so I have already got that.

Comment: Than at least we verified you have the correct bits installed :-(

Comment: Yeah, I are sad too :-(

Comment: Update: Just installed SQL Server CE 3.5 SP2 for Windows Desktop and was able to get the SqlToolbox thing to work in VS _but_ still can't edit tables :-/.

Comment: Alright, let's see if this works. The last version of VS I remember opening and editing SDF files in was VS 2012. I just installed VS 2012 Express for Web and am going to see if it'll work for me.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. I've installed a previous version of VS since I cannot get it working with VS 2013. Really wasn't something I wanted to do - but atleast I can work now.

Comment: Lest not forget that VS2013 is still a preview release, hopefully things like this will be resolved in the final bits.

Comment: @MarkHall Oh yeah ofcourse. It's still preview release but I was getting a little scared. When 4+ apps wouldn't edit them (and some couldn't even open them), and given the complete lack of support for sql ce db's in vs 2013 (as far as I could tell in the past week), and many google searches revealed others with the same problems, it made me wonder if I should start migrating to remote sql db.

Comment: Actually I know what it feels like, I am still migrating to VS2012, I have to redo all of my installers, which is a pain.

Comment: well.. not this has bit me as well. seriously, we can't edit sdf files now? the ms insanity continues.

Answer (score 47):

The answer is yes: Microsoft is silently dropping support (as usual IMHO) to Sql Compact Edition.

It started abandoning Sql CE 3.5 in Vs2012
It continued dropping Sql CE in Sql Management Studio 2012
and finally in VS2013

You can use [CompactView](http://sourceforge.net/projects/compactview/) or install SQL [Server Compact Toolbox](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1) extension in VS2013 or (my prefered solution) use [Sql management Studio 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593)

UPDATE thanks to [Nicolas' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598506/is-microsoft-dropping-support-for-sdf-database-files-in-visual-studio/19561391?noredirect=1#comment33507209_19561391)

As [stated by Microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/776328/port-sql-compact-to-windows-rt#ctl00_MasterBody_upCommunityComments):

> SQL Server compact edition is in deprecation mode with no new releases
>   planned near future. Last release SQL CE 4.0SP1 (and earlier releases
>   that are still in the support cycle) will continue to be supported
>   through its lifecycle and Microsoft is committed to fix any major,
>   production blocking issues found in these releases.

Comment: See the reply from MS on this article: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/776328/port-sql-compact-to-windows-rt

Comment: Why does Microsoft keep doing this?

Comment: @spike.y billion dollar question :D? maybe they hope nobody notice