# Use microsoft Sql Server Compact 3.5 without upgrading sdf files in Visual Studio 2013 or 2012

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-ce, compact-framework

I have `sql server` compact file in `3.5 version` which I need to use in desktop application which is in `Vs 2013`.But I found that this feature has been not supported in `vs 2013`.Is there any way I can use the `.sdf` file of `version 3.5` in `vs 2013`.

Comment: You can use Compact View in `VS 2013`. Check [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598506/is-microsoft-dropping-support-for-sdf-database-files-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use my free Visual Studio extension: SQL Server Compact Toolbox, just got to Tools, Extensions and Updates, Online