# No Local Database in list of Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, local-database

Hello I'm trying create local database with Visual Studio 2015, but in items list I have no any Local Database, there is only Dataset and Service-based Database and with Search Templates also nothing. Can you help me figure out, what I have to do, where and how to get it to use?

Comment: Did you do a custom install? Are you sure that you installed "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools" with your install?  You may have to re-run the setup of Visual studio, select modify, and check that option.

Comment: @Claire but can I download it and just install ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt204009.aspx

Comment: To quickly see if you are missing the installation you can check in View to see if you can open the SQL Server Object Explorer window (default shortcut is ctrl + /, ctrl + s)

Comment: @Kolichikov yes I see it SQL Server Object Explorer, seems it is already there...

Comment: See my answer below. See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598506/is-microsoft-dropping-support-for-sdf-database-files-in-visual-studio) for why the Local Database option is no longer available. Looks like Microsoft is dropping support for sdf databases (the Local Database option pre VS2013).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like in Visual Studio 2015, the way to add a local database is to select the Service Database option, and to set up a data source pointing to the resulting database file.

MSDN has a tutorial for this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms233763(v=vs.140).aspx).  They also note [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yft2c9ad(v=vs.120).aspx) that not all projects support opening the data sources window.  If you need to setup a local database with something like ASP.NET MVC, you can refer to [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller) tutorial on setting up a localdb database.